# What does שעטנז (sha'atnez) mean?

Tags: words, hebrew, etymology, shaatnez

.שעטנז.
I'm asking about the literal meaning behind the word, its etymology, etc.

Comment: Is [Kilayim 9:8](http://www.emishnah.com/PDFs/Kil'ayim09.pdf) to drash-y for you?

Comment: @DoubleAA - It's cute, but then again, it is mishnah.  Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because I don't think it's the literal meaning. Midrash is midrash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wilhelm Gesenius suggests in his Hebrew Dictionary of Tanach that the word derives from the Coptic *saht* (woven) + *nuje* (false). He also notes the [Septuagent](http://www.jeffzizz.com/files/Septuagint.pdf)'s rendering κίβδηλος (spurious). A pdf of the dictionary page can be found [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/A_Hebrew_and_English_Lexicon_%28Brown-Driver-Briggs%29.djvu/page1067-687px-A_Hebrew_and_English_Lexicon_%28Brown-Driver-Briggs%29.djvu.jpg).

Ibn Ezra already notes in his commentary to [Vayikra 19:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=265) that the word is a [*dis legomenon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dis_legomenon) and as such we can't know for sure what its exact meaning is other than that of [linsey-woolsey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woolsey-linsey) which is given in the verse itself ([Devarim 22:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0522.htm#11)):

> לֹא תִלְבַּשׁ שַׁעַטְנֵז, צֶמֶר וּפִשְׁתִּים יַחְדָּו
> Do not wear Sha'atnez, wool and linen together.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2904/discussion-between-msh210-and-double-aa)

Answer (score 7):

Per Gemara Yevamos 5: it is Roshei taivos for שוע טווי ונוז.

The [Even Ezra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=265) translates Shatnez as mixture.

http://www.ou.org/torah/article/kilayim_9_7-8

> וראיתי לאחד מרבותינו שפירש שוע טווי הצמר לבד והפשתים לבד, ונוז כלומר
>   ואח"כ נוז דהיינו שניהם ארוגים יחד